# How to loop through an array in php with formatted html design?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I want to loop through an array with formatted HTML that set up before.
For ex:

```
$display_format = "%address%<br>%zipcode% %city%<br>&euro; %price% / %m2% m2"
```

And I have an array like this:

```
$array_display = array (array ( 'address' => 'Prins Hendriklaan 15','zipcode' => '1075', 'city' => 'Amsterdam', 'price' => 6750000, 'm2' => 428 ), array ( 'address' => 'Huizingalaan', 'zipcode' =>'187 189-191', 'city'=> Amsterdam, 'price' => 3000000, 'm2' => 1.155) )
```

so I want to loop through $array_display and display each row into the formated design from $display_format. And most importantly, when I update the order or add more field or format of $display_format then it would be changed accordingly from the loop of array, no hardcode when looping through array for fixed field order( this is the most difficult part).

Can anybody help me to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you tried, show us your best attempt (code) and what does not work as expected? Please read [ask].

Comment: I do not know about the solution yet.

Comment: `Warning: Use of undefined constant Amsterdam - assumed 'Amsterdam'` - there is an error ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After correcting the small mistook about the unquote value - `Amsterdam` '-) you can use `preg_replace` with a pattern based upon the array keys found in the source data ($array_display)

```
<?php

    $array_display = array ( 
        array (
            'address'   => 'Prins Hendriklaan 15',
            'zipcode'   => '1075',
            'city'      => 'Amsterdam',
            'price'     => 6750000,
            'm2'        => 428
        ), 
        array (
            'address'   => 'Huizingalaan', 
            'zipcode'   => '187 189-191', 
            'city'      => 'Amsterdam', 
            'price'     => 3000000, 
            'm2'        => 1.155
        )
    );
    
    
    $display_format = "%address%<br>%zipcode% %city%<br>&euro; %price% / %m2% m2";
    
    foreach( $array_display as $i=>$arr ){
        $keys=array_keys( $arr );
        $tmp=$display_format;
        foreach( $keys as $key ){
            $pttn=sprintf('@%%%s%%@',$key);
            $tmp=preg_replace($pttn,$arr[$key],$tmp);
        }
        echo $tmp;
    }

?>
```

Which yields:

```
Prins Hendriklaan 15
1075 Amsterdam
€ 6750000 / 428 m2Huizingalaan
187 189-191 Amsterdam
€ 3000000 / 1.155 m2
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your array data `'city' => Amsterdam`, fixed that to `'city' => 'Amsterdam'`.

Loop through the array, `$placeholders = array_map(function($value) { return "%$value%"; }, array_keys($display));` will create a list of values to replace from your array keys (`%address%`, `%city%` ...), then replace them with the actual values from the arrays.

This code does *not* check for existence of the "placeholders" in your `$display_format`

```
$display_format = "%address%<br>%zipcode% %city%<br>&euro; %price% / %m2% m2";
$array_display = array (array ( 'address' => 'Prins Hendriklaan 15','zipcode' => '1075', 'city' => 'Amsterdam', 'price' => 6750000, 'm2' => 428 ), array ( 'address' => 'Huizingalaan', 'zipcode' =>'187 189-191', 'city'=> 'Amsterdam', 'price' => 3000000, 'm2' => 1.155) );

foreach ($array_display as $display) {
    $placeholders = array_map(function($value) { return "%$value%"; }, array_keys($display));
    echo str_replace($placeholders, $display, $display_format);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```php
<?php

$array_display = array( array ( 'address' => 'Prins Hendriklaan 15','zipcode' => '1075', 'city' => 'Amsterdam', 'price' => 6750000, 'm2' => 428 ), array ( 'address' => 'Huizingalaan', 'zipcode' =>'187 189-191', 'city'=> 'Amsterdam', 'price' => 3000000, 'm2' => 1.155) );

foreach($array_display as $displayItem) {
    $display_format = "{$displayItem['address']}<br>{$displayItem['zipcode']} {$displayItem['city']}<br>&euro; {$displayItem['price']} / {$displayItem['m2']} m2";
}
```

Edit: made a solution that didn't work

Comment: but I want to do it dynamically, for ex: I can change the display format order and add more field, then what you are doing cannot solve problem.

Comment: you are hardcode into the $display_format which is not working when I change the format of display, because I want to do that automatically. Do not need to update into the loop again everytime I update the format

Comment: @JackTrinh You're not looking for the word "automatically" but "magically". How would anyone, including yourself, be able to predict what changes in the format of display you'd be needing whenever you add arbitrary known data?